# Python - should class attributes be passed to class methods as local variables?

Tags: python, class, methods

I have been working on trying to understand classes and OOP. I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006127/python-importing-class-attributes-into-method-local-namespace) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151068/python-are-class-attributes-equivalent-to-local-variables-when-inside-a-method), but I think my question is more basic. My understanding was that in procedural code it was better to have variables passed to a function and added to the local namespace instead of accessing global variables (which should be explicitly declared). But I see lots of references where class methods refer directly to instance attributes. For example:

```
#procedural approach with local namespace
a = 5
def my_local_func(a):
    return a + 1

#procedural approach with global variable
a = 5
def my_global_func():
    global a
    return a + 1

#but it doesn't seem necessary in examples about classes
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 5

    def dosomething(self):
        return self.a + 1
```

It seems to me that the class namespace is just a subset of the global namespace, so it's not clear to me why the rules or at least convention change in this case. What I really care about is using passed instance attributes to create more complex instance attributes via a property decorator:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self)
        self.a = 5
        self.b = 1

    @property
    def c(self):    
    return self.a + self.b

    @c.setter
    def c(self, value):
        self.b = value
        return self.a + self.b
```

Actually, now that I think about it, I am passing the entire self object to the method. So in that case the object is copied into the method (local) namespace, as are its attributes, and it just happens to have the same names as the attributes in the instance namespace. I would appreciate feedback letting me know if I am thinking about this correctly....I can't be the only person who has wondered about this.

Comment: Nothing just "happens" to have the same names: that's the entire reason that `self` is passed. But I'm not sure what you're asking. (Also `self` isn't copied, it's passed by reference)

Comment: @David: Thank you. This was helpful. In the book I have been working through, it basically just said don't forget to add self as a required argument in class methods without really talking about why. So I thought the class methods were pointing to the reference in the instance namespace rather than referring to the method local namespace. This clears it up for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I get it now. Thanks to David for his comments.

In the book I have been reading on classes, it says class methods need to have self added, but it doesn't explain why. When I saw references in the method referring to self.a or self.b, I assumed it was making references directly to the instance namespace, because I hadn't thought about the implications of passing an object called self to the method. So the references to the object are passed into the local namespace, and the method is making local references, which is consistent with the behavior of functions in the global namespace.

It was helpful just to ask the question - sorry if I wasted anyone's time reading it.